# Hide Liferay control panel options form users

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide

I am developing a liferay portlet using liferay6.1 and SDK for Java.

When user logs in and they click on control panel they can see all kind of options. Is there a way to hide this options?

I am still new but i think that you can hide it from the portal.ext.properties but I am not sure and I have no idea.

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration can be do by role-permissions of user and power-user. Go to "Control Panel" -> "Roles" -> Looking for User-Role (then Power-User) -> Define Permissions. Disable in area "Permission for Control Panel" the View-Permission for Items that must be hide.

Over.

Comment: I'm using Liferay 7 and I'm willing to hide some items of control panel depending on roles. As @Mark has written I opened "Define Permissions", but everything is already unchecked. What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can show/hide control panel entries by implementing the interface `com.liferay.portlet.ControlPanelEntry`. This interface defines a couple of methods (`isVisible`/`hasAccessPermission`) that determine if a particular user sees/has access to one of the control panel entries.

The association between a portlet and its ControlPanelEntry class is defined in the `liferay-portlet.xml` configuration file. To override its value, you must use the ext-plugin.

Take a look at http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-portlet-app_6_1_0.dtd for more information (search for control-panel-entry).

Answer (score 0):

[Hide and disable access to liferay  control panel](http://java-liferay.blogspot.com/2012/07/hide-and-disable-access-to-liferays-61.html)

This blog will help you

Comment: the problem is that i want to hide only some of the options from the control panel not the controlpanel itself